# Nuget package restore failed in sitecore habitat project in vsts

Tags: deployment, paas

I am trying to setup CI/CD for sitecore habitat project. I just downloaded latest source and trying to setup the build definition.

I'm getting below error when restoring the package.

> Unable to resolve
>   'D:\a\1\s\src\foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj'
>   for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
>       Unable to resolve 'D:\a\1\s\src\foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj'
>   for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win)'.
>       Unable to resolve 'D:\a\1\s\src\foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj'
>   for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win-x64)'.
>       Unable to resolve 'D:\a\1\s\src\foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj'
>   for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win-x86)'.

Below is just a build definition. I would like to setup build definition like this. 
https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2017/08/31/continuous-integration-and-deployment-of-sitecore-habitathelix-as-an-azure-web-app/

Comment: Issue resolved when adding Nuget tool installer task above Nuget restore task.

Comment: Can you fix this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Nuget Tool Installer task to be added before restoring the nuget package. Please take a look at below screenshot.

[image]